# Cannot initialize Electron to Angular project or Vice versa despite following all stack overflow articles on subject

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

So I've tried to initialize an electron project into an angular project. When I run `ng build --prod && electron .` or `ng build --base-href ./ && electron .`, I get one of two errors depending on where I've placed the electron main.js file. In the src file, I get the error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
/Users/jaredjackson/Programming/Git/cinema-center/src/main.js:1
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
                                     ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at wrapSafe
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "cinema-center",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "src/main",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng build --prod && electron .",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron ."
```

When I place the main.js file in the root project directory and update the package.json, I get this error:

`Unable to find Electron app at /Users/jaredjackson/Programming/Git/cinema-center. Cannot find module '/Users/jaredjackson/Programming/Git/cinema-center/main.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry`

I have added `"type": "module",` to the package .json as well, it does not work.

I started the project using `ng new` and `npm install --save-dev electron` as well as `npm install --save-dev -g electron`. I also tried to redo it by installing electron from electron-forge first and then running `ng new`.

Here is my main.js file:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

My node version is v14.16.1 and my npm version is 7.14.0. Angular Cli is 11.2.14.

Answer (score 0):

electron use CommonJS module,
Change the main.js header to below:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");
```

Comment: That's essentially what the boilerplate code in main.js does. The problem isn't that I can't open an electron window, it's the electron module cannot be imported, as the error messages reveal.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install electron --save-dev`

you can refer this document to get further:

https://dzone.com/articles/tutorial-use-angular-and-electron-to-create-a-desk